# How can this random python behaviour be explained?

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

This small script generates a random float beween 0 and 1 and then if its less than "0.000111111111111" it will print the message "found it"

```
import random

value = 0.4 / 3600
print value

while True:
    rand = random.random()

    print "RAND IS: " + str(rand) + "----- VAL IS " + str(value)
    if rand < value:
        print "found it"
```

So seemingly the script runs and it never actually "finds it", however when I comment out the print statement before the if statement the command line is FILLED with "found it" even though the rand value isn't less than value. What the hell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program does find numbers that are both smaller and larger than 'value', whether or not it prints all of them out.  It's just that the output, *both ways*, is confusing you.  This is because: (a) your computer is *faster* than you can probably imagine, as long as it doesn't have to print anything; (b) but when it *does* have to print something it slows down to the point where you can actually see the printouts go by; (c) the number of iterations in between successful "findings" is bigger than you may have expected.

To demonstrate all of the above, I wrote *this* script:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import time
import random
import csv
import sys

def how_long_until(v):
    n = 0
    start = time.clock()
    rng = random.random
    while True:
        n += 1
        if rng() < v: break
    stop = time.clock()
    return n, stop - start

wr = csv.writer(sys.stdout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
wr.writerow(("loops", "cpu.time"))

value = 0.4 / 3600
for _ in range(10000):
    wr.writerow(how_long_until(value))
```

This generates random numbers until it finds one less than your "value", and then it writes out the number of loop iterations and the elapsed CPU time to find it.  It does this TEN THOUSAND TIMES.  On my computer, which is old but not *that* old, this program took *six seconds* to run.

And then I plotted histograms of both.  First, let's look at the number of loops:

[image: Histogram of number of loops needed to find a small random number, with inset zoom-in on the range 0...20000]

You can see that, although it often takes only a few thousand iterations to find a random number smaller than 0.4/3600, it *can* take as many as 80,000 iterations!  This is why it might have seemed to you that "found it" was never being printed.

Now let's look at elapsed time:

[image: Histogram of CPU time in milliseconds needed to find a small random number]

It looks very similar to the histogram of the number of loops, but notice the X-axis scale.  That's time in *milliseconds*.  Even when it takes 80,000 iterations to find the next number smaller than 0.4/3600, it only takes the computer *four milliseconds* to accomplish that feat!  This is why it seemed to you that "found it" was *continuously* getting printed when you commented out the per-iteration printout.

Comment: Wow. Like the analysis, might steal the writer part.  You added the break to your code, which as mentioned above, was the missing part.

Comment: @Hashman It wasn't (and indeed still isn't) clear to me whether OP _wanted_ the script to stop when it found a sufficiently small value.  The `csv` stdlib module is under-appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your while loop is designed to run forever as `True` is always `True`. You never break out of that infinite loop. Even if it finds the value, it just prints it because the condition you give to the while loop is still True. Since you cannot change the condition, you need to add a break statement:

```
while True:
    rand = random.random()
    print "RAND IS: " + str(rand) + "----- VAL IS " + str(value)
    if rand < value:
        print "found it"
        break
```

Comment: Thanks, I think i'm going insane